# php include error

Tags: php, css, http-headers

I am trying to include a header which i made separately into my index page. When I try to include and run it, it does not display the header that I made although the paths are all correct. please help me on this. thanks. I am a newbie in php, css and html.
Here is the link for pictures and codes: http://www.fileden.com/files/2011/7/27/3174077/My_Documents/Folder.rar

include code:

```
</head>
<body>
   <div id="main_container">

   <div>
      <?php

          include 'include/header2.php';

      ?>

        </div>

<div class="main_content">



    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
        <li><a class="current" href="../../index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="module/jo.php">Job Orders<!--[if IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
        <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
            <ul>
```

so on and so forth...

Comment: What output are you getting and have you turned on error reporting, if yes, are there any errors? Also, what does your header2.php look like?

Comment: have you enabled showing warnings and notices? (hint: you haven't)

Comment: @ancide... there is no error.. only that it does not display... I've checke the path and it's correct. I don't know why it does not show when i try to run it..

Comment: @yi_H no i have not because i don't know. I'm sorry because I'm a newbie in php..

Comment: look around here http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, turn on error reporting and see what php is telling you. You can also try to give an absolute path for your include, like:

```
include('/var/web/include/header2.php');
```

It's not really advisable to use absolute paths like this, but it might help you find out what exactly is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess, but I think 'include/header2.php' is pointing at something other than what you intend it to.  Take a look at the docs on [include path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path).  You can check your current include_path with phpinfo and work from there.